# Kernel panic on boot: not syncing (HP dv6, Ubuntu 12.10 64bit)

Tags: boot, 12.10, kernel, hp

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 64bit on an HP Pavillion dv6.
Everything works fine except I randomly get a kernel panic "not syncing" when booting.
After manually rebooting I usually get the same error; after few iterations where I try different configurations (e.g. on battery vs plugged) it usually resumes working as normal and no damage is done.

After trying to troubleshoot the issue I come to the conclusion that it must be the acpi module failing: it would seem that, if I shut down the laptop when on battery power, unless I start it on battery I would get the kernel panic.

Is this a known issue? I do not know the acpi internals enough to know where to look.

Edit: It would also be nice to know if upgrading to more recent versions of Ubuntu has a chance of solving the issue (e.g. has the acpi module been upgraded with changes that may be relevant to this problem?)

Comment: This will not be very constructive but... I've personnaly always had issues with 12.10 that were all resolved with 13.04 and 13.10.